# Loop using foreach in a collection where contains

Tags: laravel-5, collections

I want to get records using foreach in view on collections only where contain 'transCode' or where 'transCode' exist. The collection contains other items in the array, but i want to foreach only where contains

this is my collection

```
Collection {#519 ▼ 

#items: array:19 [▼
    754924 => Collection {#500 ▼
      #items: array:4 [▼
        0 => {#441 ▼
          +"Staff_Number": "754924"
          +"opening_bal": "426.44"
        }
        1 => {#465 ▼
          +"Staff_Number": "754924"
          +"total": "390.00"
          +"transCode": "CONTRIBUTION"
        }
        2 => {#478 ▼
          +"Staff_Number": "754924"
          +"total": "136.44"
          +"transCode": "INTEREST"
        }
        3 => {#497 ▼
          +"Staff_Number": "754924"
          +"total": "-100.00"
          +"transCode": "PARTIAL WITHDRAWAL"
        }
      ]
    }
    754928 => Collection {#501 ▼
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => {#436 ▼
          +"Staff_Number": "754928"
          +"opening_bal": "311.81"
        }
        1 => {#464 ▼
          +"Staff_Number": "754928"
          +"total": "231.00"
          +"transCode": "CONTRIBUTION"
        }
        2 => {#479 ▼
          +"Staff_Number": "754928"
          +"total": "80.81"
          +"transCode": "INTEREST"
        }
      ]
    }
    754981 => Collection {#502 ▶}
    754989 => Collection {#503 ▶}
    754995 => Collection {#504 ▶}
```

so i will get something like

```
CONTRIBUTION: 390.00 
INTEREST: 136.44 
PARTIAL WITHDRAWAL: -100.00
```

so something like this

```
@foreach ($results->where contains as $row)

  {{ $row->transCode }}: {{ $row->total }}

@endforeach
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a filter on your collection.

Here this should give you a headstart:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-filter

Try too do this inside your controller so that your vieuw stays clean

Comment: Thank you, but if i  filter in the controller how do I get the rejected to the the view in the same collection. I still want to send the whole collection the view and filter in the view

Comment: If you want to pass the whole collection too the view and a filtered one make a separte collection in your controller. Or use the filter method in your view. Its not a pretty solution but ik works